# When are SignalR hubs created?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

My understanding is that a new server-side Hub instance is created each time a client calls a hub method (via its hub proxy). But what if I wanted a Hub that would only be used (by server business logic) to send messages to clients, using this syntax:-

```
Clients.All.Notify(data);
```

I would be using a .Net client by the way, which would receive such messages using this sort of syntax:-

```
_myHubProxy.On<SomeData>("Notify", data => ...);
```

If the client never calls any hub methods then would the hub ever be instantiated?

**Edit**
The article provided by Nikola.Lukovic (see comment below) says:

> SignalR creates a new instance of your Hub class each time it needs to handle a Hub operation such as when a client connects, disconnects, or makes a method call to the server.

While I (kind of) understand the need to instantiate a hub each time a method is called, I'm curious as to why it also has to do this when connecting (and disconnecting). I wonder if one of its tasks is to set up the "link" between the Hub and any `On<T>` event handlers specified on the client's hub proxy?

Comment: Hub is instantiated only when a client calls a server method or connects, reconnects and disconnects. Server invoking client methods will work as soon as you call Start method from IHubConnection and OnConnected method is invoked in a Hub.
Also read about [Hub object lifetime](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubclass)